# Why does my code replace the jQuery.error function?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which seems to override the jQuery.error function:

```
    $.test = function(){
        var test = this;

        test.error = function(){
            console.log('Why is this function getting called');
        };    
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var someObj = $.test();
        $.error();
    });
```

This code will output 'Why is this function getting called' in the console.

However, if I change my code slightly, the native jQuery error function is called:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var someObj =  new $.test();
    $.error();
});
```

It seems that in the first example, 'this' refers to jQuery, but in the second example it refers to someObj. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `$.test` is a new property on the `$` object.  So it makes sense that the `this` object inside that method -- the scope of the method -- is object to which the property belongs.

An example without jQuery (on fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kxncT/):

```
var a = {};

a.method = function() {
    alert(this === a);  // true
};

a.method();
```

However, when you call the `new` operator, you're invoking a constructor.  In that case, a new scope is created for the new object.  So if in the above example you call `new a.method()`, the alert will read `false`, because the new scope that's created is new, and unrelated to the parent object.

In writing this answer, I've tried to paraphrase what I read in this blog post: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/
The post is much better than my answer, and if there are any discrepancies, trust the post :)

Comment: Thanks. This makes a lot of sense.